# how can i make dynamic linearlayout to show textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a dynamic text view. When a user enters any data in the edit view pressed ok, that data will show on text view in horizontal. That data will auto set in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and if that data is not placed on that line automatic set in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            str += ", " + editText.text
            textView.text = str
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        }
        return@setOnEditorActionListener false
    }
```

and set below attribute for edittet in the layout:

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```